# Getting Xpath node values in nested XML

Tags: xml, xpath

My xml structure is like,

```
<items>
<item>
    <brand>
        <id> 3 </id>
     </brand>
    <product>
        <productType>Type 1</productType>
    </product>
</item>
<item>
    <brand>
        <id> 4 </id>
     </brand>
    <product>
        <productType>Type 2</productType>
    </product>
</item>
</items>
```

I need to get the product type value if the user provides the brand id. For eg, if the user enters brand id 3, then I need to return the product type **Type 1**

I tried with Xpath expression

```
 /items/item/brand[id = 3]/product/productType
```

But it does not work. What will be the correct xpath expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple nesting problem since `brand` is a **sibling** to `product` and **not an anscestor** like your XPath query implies.

Simply change to:

```
/items/item[brand/id = 3]/product/productType
```

Result:

```
Element='<productType>Type 1</productType>'
```

Try it at http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.